# I want to traverse a list using multiple workers in celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a list:

```
 url_list=["abc.com","def.com","xyz.com"."pqr.com"...] - 100,000 entries
```

I want to traverse this list using 100 celery workers to reduce the time it takes to do it.

My question is: How do I provide this `url_list` to the workers, so that these 100 celery workers shoot on the `url_list` at once, without hitting the element of the list, that has already been traversed by some other worker?

I have made a directory, *proj-> celery.py, tasks.py*

As I understood, I will mention my task in the *tasks.py* file, and call the task using `.delay` function in python shell. And *celery.py* will contain the configurations stuff.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

In another words you have 100 processes receiving the same list which they need to share the state (node visited True/False)

You need to communicate between the processes somehow, meaning the task needs to share the object with the other workers running the task.

IMO this is not very efficient and may give you headaches and generate bugs, maybe a map/reduce approach would be easier, meaning that before calling the tasks you separate what part of the list each worker will get.

You don't need to separate in 100 jobs, you can divide the 100k entries list in 10 entries list, so each worker would process 10 entries at a time, and once finished it would get the next batch from the queue

Comment: so basically what i understand by what you're saying is: Like if I have 100,000 urls, while calling the .delay() function, i should pass the starting index and ending index for each worker as arguments. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: you could, but rather than passing the list plus indexes I believe it is better to pass just the relevant slice

Comment: right. 
For my information, is there any way to share this list of urls between the workers?

Comment: any interprocess communication, you can use a file or socket for example